# How to compute the norm operator of operators in $L(\mathbb R^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand how the norm operator
$$||A||=\sup \{||Ax||: x\in \mathbb R^2\text{ with } ||x||=1\}$$
works and how to calculate it for operators in $L(\mathbb R^2)$.

If the operator is given by
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&2
\end{matrix}\right],$$
is it correct to say that
$$||A||=\infty$$
since for $h=(h_1,h_2) \in \mathbb R^2 $ with $||h||=1$ we have that $||Ah||= \sqrt{1+3h_2^2}$?

If the operator is given by
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{matrix}\right],$$
is it correct to say that
$$||A||=1$$
since for $h=(h_1,h_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ with $||h||=1$ we have that $||Ah||= 1$?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first example,
$$\sup\{\|Ax\|: \|x\|=1\}=\sup\{\sqrt{x_1^2+(2x_2)^2}:\|x\|=1\}.$$
Why you think it is infinite ?
To see what is the sup, you can remove the $\sqrt{}$. You know $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$, so $x_1^2+4(1-x_1^2)$ is maximal when $x_1=0$. Therefore the sup is equal to $\sqrt{0^2+(2*1)^2}=2$.

Your second example is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was infinite because I was considering the expression $\sqrt{1+3h_2^2}$ as a function. But now I see my misunderstanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the first case $A(h_1,h_2)=(h_1,2h_2)$ and $\|A(h_1,h_2)\|=\sqrt{h_1^{2}+4h_2^{2}}\leq \sqrt{1+3h_2^{2}}\leq 2$ when $h_1^{2}+h_2^{2}=1$. The value $2$ is attained when $h_1=0$ and $h_2=1$. So $\|A\|=2$. For the second one your answer is correct.

Comment: Now I see my error. Thanks for that.

Comment: By the way, using this approach, then I get $||A||=1$ for $A=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Norm of a linear map on $\mathbb R^{2}$ is always finite.  @learningmaths

Comment: Is it always finite due to the constrain $||x||=1$ or because $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension 2?

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand this. If $A=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$, then $||A||= \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$. What do you think? Thanks again.